# How to populate an html table from angular http get that returns an array of JSON

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table, rxjs, observable

I have a service that returns an array of JSON objects that I am attempting to load into an html table.  The http get is returning data however the data will not load into the table.  I suspect I may have an issue with the data types I am using in my typescript code.  This code is logging no errors to the console.

If I comment out the data table and add a new line with {{ myData }} the page displays "function values() { [native code] }"

**my-data.component.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>
      My Data
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <app-loader [isLoading]="isLoading"></app-loader>
    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive" [hidden]="isLoading">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" data-field="myData.fileName">File Name</th>
            <th scope="col" data-field="myData.index">Index</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**my-data.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { MyService } from './my-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-data',
  templateUrl: './my-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-data.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  myData: any;
  isLoading: boolean;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.myService
      .getMyData()
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        })
      )
      .subscribe((myData: any) => {
        this.myData = myData;
      });
  }
}
```

**my-data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

const routes = {
  dataEndpoint: 'http://localhost:53452/api/data'
};

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getMyData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient
      .cache()
      .get(routes.dataEndpoint)
      .pipe(
        map((body: any) => body.values),
        catchError(() => of('Error, could not load My Data'))
      );
  }
}
```

**JSON Returned from get**

```
[{"fileName":"sometext.txt", "index": 1},{"fileName":"sometext2.txt", "index": 2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are trying to display the data in the table body. Try this.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>
      My Data
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <app-loader [isLoading]="isLoading"></app-loader>
    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive" [hidden]="isLoading">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">File Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Index</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let file of myData">
            <td>{{file.fileName}}</td>
            <td>{{file.index}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was helpful but the real problem was in the service.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is an array, so you have to use `*ngFor`, like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>
      My Data
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <app-loader [isLoading]="isLoading"></app-loader>
    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive" [hidden]="isLoading">
      <thead>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of myData">
            <th scope="col" data-field="data.fileName">File Name</th>
            <th scope="col" data-field="data.index">Index</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was helpful but the real problem was in the service.

Comment: does the service return this data?
What does he really return?

Answer (score 0):

I had to update the service to fix the problem which involved adding an interface and changing body.values to body. See https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response for more information.

**Updated my-data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

const routes = {
  dataEndpoint: 'http://localhost:53452/api/data'
};

export interface MyDataContext {
  FileName: string;
  Index: number;
}

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getMyData(): Observable<MyDataContext> {
    return this.httpClient
      .cache()
      .get<MyDataContext>(routes.dataEndpoint)
      .pipe(
        map((body: any) => body),
        catchError(() => of('Error, could not load My Data'))
      );
  }
}
```